# Increase distance to page numbers in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like to know how to decrease the column width in the ToC so that the white distance to the page numbers increase.
Thanks a lot!

[image]

This is the result when I use:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{2em}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: tocloft?  titlesec?  Preference on compiling engine?

Comment: Tough crowd sometimes! It's likely this is a duplicate. That said, see if [this QA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132064/changing-the-table-of-contents-width) or [this QA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-space-between-the-numbers-and-text-of-sectioning-titles-in-the/33842#33842) gets you started. If not, a more complete MWE would help. `Charter` is a font; so, it's not part of the problem. And, it'd be Ok to edit the Q to remove `tables` and `columns` tags, since this is a ToC issue. `tables` and `columns` are typically in the body of the doc.

Comment: Does it matter if you redefine \@pnumwidth before you load packages?

Comment: No difference ...

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows us which class you are using, if there are modifications to the toc etc.?

Comment: @mldmnn Who's on-line when can be a challenge sometimes. Are the leader dots appearing at the chapter level, the section level, subsection, etc.?  Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55465/remove-dots-page-numbers-from-toc) help? (It seems a shame to give away more than half your points on this,)

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- since there's no difference between redefining `\@pnumwidth` before or after loading packages. i'd try putting the redefinition *after* loading all packages, and further, wrapping it in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3cm}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4cm}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer
  longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer}

Foo.

\chapter{Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer
  longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer}

Bar.

\chapter{Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer
  longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer Longer longer longer longer}

Bar.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked for me! But now dots appear. How to get rid of it?

Comment: If you have dots, it must be due to some other package that you are using. I've edited my answer to include a MWE without dots.

Comment: @EricMarsden See if the chapters are producing the dots, or the sections, e.g., [this scenario](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148814/customization-of-chapter-entries-in-table-of-contents/148816#148816)

Comment: You're right, dots are produced by sections. I updated the MWE to remove dots.

Comment: @EricMarsden Good work.